# Password protect directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a wordpress multisite install that has a host of sub-sites in dynamic/virtual folders. For example, http://www.mysite.com/ is the main root dir, with a sub-site sitting dynamically in http://www.mysite.com/subsite/. Now, the sub-directory 'subsite' doesn't physically exist but is created by wordpress.

I would like to know if it's possible to protect one of these directories that doesn't physically exist using .htaccess/.htpasswd?

I've tried creating a physical version of the directory, but it then breaks my wordpress installation.

I just need a line of code in the .htaccess that tells it which folder it should be targeting/protecting rather than having to actually place it in the directory.

Hope this makes sense, any help appreciated, S.

Comment: This question would be more at home at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot use `.htaccess` for *virtual* paths handled by web apps.

I'm not a wordpress user, but there seem to be several wordpress plugins that allow you to password protect your wordpress site.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/http-authentication/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/askapache-password-protect/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-password/
- (and [many more](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=password)...)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do probably is related to my issue with wp-admin security via .htaccess / htpasswd.

The virtual directory authentication does not happen due to the WP rewrite rules for the MU/Network config.

You should be able to do something similar to the solution I used.

http://howden.net.au/thowden/2011/03/wordpress-404-error-password-admin-directory/

The issue with answer #1 is that all of the htaccess / htpasswd related setups, whether a WP plugin or manually done by the site admin or done via cpanel / plesk assume that it is not a virtual directory. The rewrite rules for the virtual directory kills the htpasswd option.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found that [Password Protected](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/password-protected/) is simple and effective if you just want to protect the (sub)site with a generic password, without creating a bunch of users.